# UIImage Picker autorotation feature disappeared suddenly

Tags: rotation, uiimagepickercontroller, orientation, preview

I was using `UIImagePickerController` without any problem.

Before when I was taking a picture in the landscape mode, the picture in the *Preview* (when the buttons Retake and Use Photo were present) was always automatically rotated so as to appear correctly in the portrait mode.

But now when I use the `UIImagePickerController` the preview mode does not rotate the picture anymore.

Where can I activate or desactivate this mode?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)getCameraPicture{



    //Create an UIImagePickerController to be able to take a picture
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release]; 


- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;//Here is specified the fact that the picker source is the library
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library" message:@"Device does not support a photo library" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Drat!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    int imageCase=0;
    UIImage *imageSaved=rotateImage(image);
    UIImage* imageNormal =scaleImage(imageSaved,imageCase);



    imageView.image = imageNormal;



    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}



- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I really need to at least understand what is happening so any help would be really appreciated even if it is not the solution!

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is that you need to call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```